# Data Model Design and Permissioning

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, data-modeling

I am working on creating [structured interviewing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_interview) app.

At a High level My DataModal looks like:

```
Class Question
   id: String
   type: ENUM => Technical, NonTechnical
   title: String
   description: String

Class Technical
   Topic: String
   Subtopic: String
   List <Example> 
   List <Solution>

Class NonTechnical 
   List <Solution>
```

I am using Hibernate/JPA and MS Sql. Questions here are

1. I want a different set of Read/Write/Update/Delete permissions on Technical and Non Technical Questions. Like only devs are allowed write access on technical questions and only HRs are allowed write access on NonTech questions etc.  Is it possible to achieve this with the data modal above or I should keep Technical and Non Technical questions in two different databases?
2. Is Hibernate a right choice or I should use Mybatis?

Leads here are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Java then I would suggest you to look at Spring Security for Roles and Permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to distinguish between application workflow versus permissioning. Typically, permissions focus on allowing different types of access to resources (e.g. "members of group x have read, but not write, permissions to file y"). Permissions are typically managed outside the application itself.

A workflow, on the other hand, says "show users of type x the following view of your application, and users of type y a different view" - for instance, Stack Overflow shows users with a high reputation a different set of tools. This is based on permissions, but usually it's "baked in" to the application.

I don't know the right answer for you, but I'd think about this before deciding on any particular framework.

To answer your first question:

> Is it possible to achieve this with the data modal above or I should
>   keep Technical and Non Technical questions in two different databases?

No, your data model is incomplete. It doesn't show how you model users - how does your application know what type of user is logged in? There is absolutely no reason to store the different types of question in different databases - it's uncommon to use database level permissions to enforce application-level security.

> Is Hibernate a right choice or I should use Mybatis?

The choice is irrelevant to the problem you describe.